# select value not taking properly

Tags: php, email

i have one big form.. there have some so many select option. and its from to mail function. bellow is my code

```
  <label>Type of Event? </label>
    <select id="eventtype" title="" name="eventtype" class="required select">
      <option value="">Select Your Event Type</option>
      <option value="WEDDINGS">WEDDINGS</option>
      <option value="CORPORATE">CORPORATE EVENT</option>
      <option value="SPECIAL">SPECIAL EVENT</option>
      <option value="OTHER">OTHER SINGLE SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <div class="cls"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="WEDDINGS">
        <label>Package</label>
        <select name="Package" id="Package">
          <option value="Day Of Coordination">Day Of Coordination</option>
          <option value="Week of Coordination">Week of Coordination</option>
          <option value="Month of Coordination">Month of Coordination</option>

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="CORPORATE">
        <label>Package</label>
        <select name="Package" id="Package">
          <option value="Meetings">Meetings</option>
          <option value="Client Appreciation">Client Appreciation</option>
          <option value="Conference &amp; Conventions">Conference &amp; Conventions</option>
          <option value="Corporate Shows">Corporate Shows</option>
          <option value="Employee Appreciation">Employee Appreciation</option>

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="SPECIAL">
        <label>Package</label>
        <select name="Package" id="Package">
          <option value="Engagements">Engagements</option>
          <option value="Bar Mitzvah">Bar Mitzvah</option>
          <option value="Quincearas">Quincearas</option>
          <option value="Birthdays">Birthdays</option>
          <option value="Fashion Shows">Fashion Shows</option>
          <option value="Showers">Showers</option>

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="OTHER">
        <label>Package</label>
        <select name="Package" id="Package">
          <option value="Wedding Consultation and Guidance Only">Wedding Consultation and Guidance Only</option>
          <option value="Venue Search Only">Venue Search Only</option>
          <option value="Coordination of Engagement Party Only">Coordination of Engagement Party Only</option>
          <option value="Providing Qualified and Screened Vendors Only">Providing Qualified and Screened Vendors Only</option>

          </select>
```

js code for realtion with drop down

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eventtype').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide();
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) {
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); 
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});


</script>
```

my from is like if select WEDDING then show Wedding div so show there another drop down.. and if select CORPORATE EVENT then show CORPORATE EVENT div... but no matter what drop down i select when mail go correct data not pass. its goes always OTHER div 1st select value mean "Wedding Consultation and Guidance Only" ... i have no idea why... may be i mistake something... bellow is part of php mail code

```
    if($violation)
{
$eventtype = $_POST['eventtype'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$datepicker = $_POST['datepicker'];
$datepicker2 = $_POST['datepicker2'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$EMAIL = $_POST['EMAIL'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$Package = $_POST['Package'];
$otherfound = $_POST['otherfound'];

if (isset($_POST['found_group'])) {
    $found = $_POST['found_group'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($found); $i++) {
        //echo $found[$i]."<br />";
        $found=implode("<br />",$found);
    }
}
```

all i want to correct data will go .. can you tell me where i am mistaking... thanks

Comment: won't work this way. you are having `<select name="Package" id="Package">` for all your selects you will need unique name and id for each of them and use needed value only at the php end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to do something like this

```
<label>Type of Event? </label>
<select id="eventtype" title="" name="eventtype" name="eventtype" class="required select">
  <option value="">Select Your Event Type</option>
  <option value="WEDDINGS">WEDDINGS</option>
  <option value="CORPORATE">CORPORATE EVENT</option>
  <option value="SPECIAL">SPECIAL EVENT</option>
  <option value="OTHER">OTHER SINGLE SERVICES</option>
</select>
<div class="cls"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="WEDDINGS">
    <label>Package</label>
    <select name="WEDDINGSPackage" id="WEDDINGSPackage">
      <option value="Day Of Coordination">Day Of Coordination</option>
      <option value="Week of Coordination">Week of Coordination</option>
      <option value="Month of Coordination">Month of Coordination</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="CORPORATE">
    <label>Package</label>
    <select name="CORPORATEPackage" id="CORPORATEPackage">
      <option value="Meetings">Meetings</option>
      <option value="Client Appreciation">Client Appreciation</option>
      <option value="Conference &amp; Conventions">Conference &amp; Conventions</option>
      <option value="Corporate Shows">Corporate Shows</option>
      <option value="Employee Appreciation">Employee Appreciation</option>

    </select>
  </div>
.......
```

and at PHP end you have to do something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['eventtype'])) {
    $subOptSelect = $_POST['eventtype'] . 'Package';
    if (isset($_POST[$subOptSelect])){
        $sub = $_POST[$subOptSelect];
    }
}
```

I have prefixed the value of the first select to the sub selects and it becomes easier at php end.

**Edit:** Here is the code you may require.

```
$package='';
if (!empty($eventtype)) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$eventtype.'Package'])){
        $package = $_POST[$eventtype.'Package'];
        //$package contains the option selected in the sub option.
    }else{
        //nothing selected in the sub dropdown. you have to add code to handle this
    }
}else{
  //nothing selected in the first dropdown. you have to add code to handle this
}
```

And your email can be:

```
<table width='95%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='11'>
<tr>
  <td width='189'>Event Type :</td>
  <td>$eventtype</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Package :</td><td>$package</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>First Name :</td><td>$firstname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse the name attribute in html, and you're html form has the same name for each select tag. What is happening is the markup is processed sequentially so it only uses the last declaration of the name="Package" select so the selected value from that will always be passed to the server as the $_POST['package']. Do something like this instead:

```
 <label>Type of Event? </label>
<select id="eventtype" title="" name="eventtype" class="required select">
  <option value="">Select Your Event Type</option>
  <option value="WEDDINGS">WEDDINGS</option>
  <option value="CORPORATE">CORPORATE EVENT</option>
  <option value="SPECIAL">SPECIAL EVENT</option>
  <option value="OTHER">OTHER SINGLE SERVICES</option>
</select>
<div class="cls"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="WEDDINGS">
    <label>Package</label>
    <select name="Weddings-Package" id="Weddings-Package">
      <option value="Day Of Coordination">Day Of Coordination</option>
      <option value="Week of Coordination">Week of Coordination</option>
      <option value="Month of Coordination">Month of Coordination</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="CORPORATE">
    <label>Package</label>
    <select name="Corporate-Package" id="Corporate-Package">
      <option value="Meetings">Meetings</option>
      <option value="Client Appreciation">Client Appreciation</option>
      <option value="Conference &amp; Conventions">Conference &amp; Conventions</option>
      <option value="Corporate Shows">Corporate Shows</option>
      <option value="Employee Appreciation">Employee Appreciation</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="SPECIAL">
    <label>Package</label>
    <select name="Special-Package" id="Special-Package">
      <option value="Engagements">Engagements</option>
      <option value="Bar Mitzvah">Bar Mitzvah</option>
      <option value="Quincearas">Quincearas</option>
      <option value="Birthdays">Birthdays</option>
      <option value="Fashion Shows">Fashion Shows</option>
      <option value="Showers">Showers</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="OTHER">
    <label>Package</label>
    <select name="Other-Package" id="Other-Package">
      <option value="Wedding Consultation and Guidance Only">Wedding Consultation and Guidance Only</option>
      <option value="Venue Search Only">Venue Search Only</option>
      <option value="Coordination of Engagement Party Only">Coordination of Engagement Party Only</option>
      <option value="Providing Qualified and Screened Vendors Only">Providing Qualified and Screened Vendors Only</option>

      </select>
```

when the post data is sent to the server it is sent in the $_POST variable as an associative array with the names as the key, if you make the name of each select unique then you should be able to achieve what you want. You might want to pass the name of which select was used to the server so you know which variable to grab in php. As another note the id value for every tag should be unique, as that is the purpose of an id attribute.